# insmod from external media during boot

Tags: init, kernel-module, insmod

I am trying to insmod a kernel module on a external media via initramfs scripts during boot process.

I want to know if after insmod the media should remain available to system or system temporarily copy it to use it?

After all is it possible to insert kernel module via external media?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, i insert my module using insmod during local-top scripts of initramfs. After inserting module it's necessary to unmount external device, else you go in to wall getting kernel panic.

module is available yet after unmounting device